# How do I fix a Bazel build error in tensorflow

Tags: c++, linux, tensorflow, ubuntu, bazel

I'm trying to build Tensorflow from source on Ubuntu20.04.1 LTS(64 bit) with python3.8, CPU. when I execute "bazel build //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package" or "bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package", it says:

```
ERROR: /home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/98c722257537c18880fe8a24953ff878/external/flatbuffers/BUILD.bazel:65:1: Linking of rule '@flatbuffers//:flatc' failed (Exit 1)
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-fuse-ld=COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS=gold
-Wl,-no-as-needed
-Wl,-z,relro,-z,now
-B/usr/lib/icecc/bin
-pass-exit-codes
-lstdc++
-lm
-Wl,--gc-sections
-Wl,--start-lib
bazel-out/host/bin/external/flatbuffers/src/_objs/flatc/flatc_main.o
bazel-out/host/bin/external/flatbuffers/src/_objs/flatc/idl_gen_cpp.o
bazel-out/host/bin/external/flatbuffers/src/_objs/flatc/idl_gen_csharp.o
bazel-out/host/bin/external/flatbuffers/src/_objs/flatc/idl_gen_dart.o
bazel-out/host/bin/external/flatbuffers/src/_objs/flatc/idl_gen_go.o
bazel-out/host/bin/external/flatbuffers/src/_objs/flatc/idl_gen_grpc.o
bazel-out/host/bin/external/flatbuffers/src/_objs/flatc/idl_gen_java.o
bazel-out/host/bin/external/flatbuffers/src/_objs/flatc/idl_gen_js_ts.o
bazel-out/host/bin/external/flatbuffers/src/_objs/flatc/idl_gen_json_schema.o
bazel-out/host/bin/external/flatbuffers/src/_objs/flatc/idl_gen_kotlin.o
bazel-out/host/bin/external/flatbuffers/src/_objs/flatc/idl_gen_lobster.o
bazel-out/host/bin/external/flatbuffers/src/_objs/flatc/idl_gen_lua.o
bazel-out/host/bin/external/flatbuffers/src/_objs/flatc/idl_gen_php.o
bazel-out/host/bin/external/flatbuffers/src/_objs/flatc/idl_gen_python.o
bazel-out/host/bin/external/flatbuffers/src/_objs/flatc/idl_gen_rust.o
bazel-out/host/bin/external/flatbuffers/src/_objs/flatc/idl_gen_text.o
bazel-out/host/bin/external/flatbuffers/src/_objs/flatc/idl_gen_swift.o
bazel-out/host/bin/external/flatbuffers/src/_objs/flatc/util.o
-Wl,--end-lib
-Wl,--start-lib
bazel-out/host/bin/external/flatbuffers/src/_objs/flatc_library/flatc.o
-Wl,--end-lib
-Wl,--start-lib
bazel-out/host/bin/external/flatbuffers/grpc/src/compiler/_objs/cpp_generator/cpp_generator.o
-Wl,--end-lib
-Wl,--start-lib
bazel-out/host/bin/external/flatbuffers/grpc/src/compiler/_objs/go_generator/go_generator.o
-Wl,--end-lib
-Wl,--start-lib
bazel-out/host/bin/external/flatbuffers/grpc/src/compiler/_objs/java_generator/java_generator.o
-Wl,--end-lib
-Wl,--start-lib
bazel-out/host/bin/external/flatbuffers/grpc/src/compiler/_objs/python_generator_private/python_generator.o
-Wl,--end-lib
-Wl,--start-lib
bazel-out/host/bin/external/flatbuffers/grpc/src/compiler/_objs/swift_generator/swift_generator.o
-Wl,--end-lib
-Wl,--start-lib
bazel-out/host/bin/external/flatbuffers/src/_objs/flatbuffers/code_generators.o
bazel-out/host/bin/external/flatbuffers/src/_objs/flatbuffers/idl_gen_fbs.o
bazel-out/host/bin/external/flatbuffers/src/_objs/flatbuffers/idl_gen_text.o
bazel-out/host/bin/external/flatbuffers/src/_objs/flatbuffers/idl_parser.o
bazel-out/host/bin/external/flatbuffers/src/_objs/flatbuffers/reflection.o
bazel-out/host/bin/external/flatbuffers/src/_objs/flatbuffers/util.o
-Wl,--end-lib
-lm
-ldl
   '
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 33.985s, Critical Path: 12.00s
INFO: 43 processes: 43 local.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

How can I Fix this error?

Comment: We're missing some details. Could you provide the bazel version and the tensorflow version that you are trying to compile?

Comment: @Lescurel Thanks for your comment! the bazel version is v3.1.0 and the tensorflow version is v2.4 !

Comment: Follow the instructions mentioned in the Tensorflow https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source. Thanks!